# Can't install joomla 3.4 (blank page)

Tags: php, joomla, server, joomla3.0, vps

I've tried installing Joomla 3.4 on to my server(upload .zip and extract everything), but everytime I want to run it, it directs me to `"installation/index.php"` then the entire page is blank. On the console menu inspect element the error I got is :

```
"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)".
```

I really have no idea what's wrong, also tried changing the file/directory permission, didnt work.

Here is the direct link to my site www.bobaking.co.uk

Here are my server specs:

> Apache Version 2.2.29
>
> PHP Version 5.4.33
>
> MySQL Version 5.5.42-cll
>
> Architecture x86_64
>
> Operating System linux

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks a lot!

Comment: It works now! just needed to enable PDO on apache, cheers Rajeev CJ!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faced same problem yesterday and solved once enabled PDO module via Easyapache update.

Comment: could you please to give more details for your answer?

Comment: Thank you! I displayed the php error and PDO was the problem indeed. Enabled it on the apache and it works now :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try changing .htaccess file configuration.